# BigQuery Connector for Excel : Incorrect parameter type

Tags: excel, google-bigquery, connector

I'm Trying to connect to Bigquery from Microsoft Excel.

I Followed the steps described in the following link :
https://bigquery-connector.appspot.com/

As asked, I've downloaded the connector (IQY file) and entered the 3 following parameters in excel : project ID, SQL query and unique key.

Next Steps consist in opening the IQY file and pointing to cells that contains the 3 parameters.

But once i point to the unique key parameter, it returns the following error :

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64bRE.png)

Error Message > ***Parameter type is not correct. Microsoft excel needs a different type of parameter from what is given.***

It`s been working with no problem with the previous key. But as the previous one was expired, i had to generate a new one from the same link above.

Any help is welcomed.
i`m available to give more details.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this problem, just used this ODBC driver:
[Link to Driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/)

With these instructions:
[Link to youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpFtx3BTcOA)

Instructions at google aren't very clear. But you will need to also Check:
[Link to by Google Instructions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-connect-bigquery-to-microsoft-excel-and-other-apps-with-our-new-odbc-driver)

After configuring the ODBC driver with your service or user access, configure Excel with google instructions, and even without a query you will be able to use powerquery to explore and query your datasets:
[Process end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AlGs.png)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, i'm unable to change  ODBC driver's system parameters as i'm don't have admin permissions. I will try contacting admins in my company, to help me do this.

Comment: @aimanarshad probably the best way to go, this way, it is a very very powerful way of processing and exploring BigQuey data.

Comment: ODBC connection worked. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

To my opinion, the unique key provided by Google seems one charater longer than expected by Excel and that is the reason  error. I didn't find the way to correct.